# How Can I Store a Wildcard in a Variable

Tags: variable, wildcards

I have the following code:

```bash
target="file.txt"
ls "$target"
```

Output:

```bash
file.txt
```

This does not work with a wildcard:

```bash
target="*"
ls "$target"
```

Output:

```bash
ls: cannot access '*': No such file or directory
```

The issue is that it is being wrapped in quotes.
It is doing `ls '*'` instead of `ls *`.

Comment: If you're trying to do stuff like this, you're almost certainly going about it the wrong way - you're re-implementing something that your shell already gives you for free.   Better to just store the results of the wildcard in an array, or iterate over the wildcard's expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quote the `$target`, you're telling the shell not to expand the wildcard. Try leaving the quotes off:

```
target="*"
ls $target
```

and you'll get a directory listing.

What other values might `target` have though? Might it have spaces? Question marks? How would you want them to be treated?

Comment: Even without quotes, it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Amarakon What shell are you using? zsh doesn't expand wildcards in variables by default, so if you're using zsh that'd explain it.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Yes, I was using ZSH. But when I used SH or BASH, it worked. Thanks for clarifying that!